# Display Html tag after reload data from database

Tags: laravel, tinymce

I am current using tinymce for my project,Its[image] store data with html tag but when I want to retrieve to blade it also show html tags,How do I figure it?

```
tinymce.init({
    selector: '.texteditor'
  });
```

Answer (score 1):

In blade the `{{ }}` will escape all the HTML special characters in order to avoid Cross Site Scripting and some other problems, and so also the tags will be escaped... if you are sure that that texts don't contain anything malicious, use `{!! $text !!}`, this will prevent the special characters escape done by blade.

You should do this when you set the `value` of the `input tag` or the text between `<textarea>` and `</textarea>`